Is this homebrew Kelpie race balanced compared to official races?
I am planning on DMing for a group of friends, and one of them asked if they would be able to play as a Kelpie. After doing some searching, I am not satisfied with the current homebrew race options that are out there (almost always they are far too strong), so I have decided to try my hand at homebrewing my own.
My goal in general is to create a race that focuses on the lore of Kelpies, while also keeping them balanced when compared to other races (I don't want the PC to be far more powerful than the others, but I also don't want to handicap them). I based the abilities off of the official Kelpie monster stat block found in Tales of the Yawning Portal, as well as the page on the Forgotten Realms fandom wiki.
The things I'm mostly concerned about are Seaweed Shifting and Water Dependency.


Kelpie Traits
Ability Score Increase. Your Charisma score increases by 1. Additionally, one other ability score of your choosing increases by 2, or two ability scores by 1 each.
Age. A Kelpie's maturity time depends on the method of reproduction. Kelpies can either be planted underwater, where they will sprout and become mature after 2 years. Alternatively, when a Kelpie becomes too large, it can split into two separate entities, which each mature after just 1 month. Kelpies generally grow large enough to split after 10 years. Due to their asexual reproduction, it is unknown how old Kelpies can truly get. You are immune to magical aging effects.
Size. Your size is Medium.
Creature Type. You are a Fey, and your true form is an amorphous mass of seaweed.
Speed. You have a walking speed of 30 feet and a swimming speed of 30 feet.
Languages. You can speak Common and Primordial (Aquan).


Most of this is decently standard. I decided to go with Fey, because Kelpies are not really humanoid, but calling them plants seemed like a headache to DM for. Making them Fey creatures means that there's already standards for how to handle them while also appealing to their mystical nature.
Kelpies are also very strange when it comes to age. To simplify things, I gave them immunity to magical aging effects. I considered making magical aging effects give them exhaustion as if they skipped their water dependency, but I couldn't figure out a good way to manage that.


Seaweed Shifting. As an action, you can reshape your body into the form of a humanoid or beast that is Small or Medium. Your statistics are otherwise unchanged. The disguise is convincing, unless you are in bright light or the viewer is within 30 feet of you, in which case the seams between the seaweed strands are visible. You return to your true form if you use a bonus action to do so, or you are killed. You cannot use your walking speed if you are in your true form, or the beast you are shifted into is unable to do so (such as a fish).


This is where things get complicated. It is difficult to balance this, especially since even Detect Balance has yet to include shapechanger, and this is certainly much less powerful than that. It's hard to consider the balance implications of such an ability.
I essentially copied the ability the monster statblock has (Seaweed Shape), but I removed the ability to morph into a large beast, and gave it the limitation of being able to walk if it wouldn't make sense. Hopefully these changes help to balance the ability.
Balance-wise, I considered this to be a much more powerful version of Disguise Self. It's far from a perfect fit, but it's the best comparison I could find.


Amphibious. You can breathe air and water.
Water Dependency. If you fail to immerse yourself in water for at least 1 hour during a day, you suffer 1 level of exhaustion at the end of that day. You can recover from this exhaustion only through magic or by immersing yourself in water for at least 1 hour.


Snagged straight from the Grung race. No sense in reinventing the wheel. It is, however, difficult to account for Water Dependency, since that's not listed in Detect Balance.


Photosynthesis. As long as you have had at least one hour of direct sunlight, you do not need to eat. You can eat normally if you are in a Humanoid shape to get around this limitation.
Siren Song. You know the Charm Person spell. After casting this spell using this trait, you must finish a long rest before you can use it again. Charisma is your spellcasting ability for this spell.


These ones are based purely on the flavor of the Kelpie. Photosynthesis isn't super powerful, but it's worth noting that as long as they have access to outdoors they don't need to eat. Balance-wise, it's not unheard of to have a level 1 spell, but it's fairly powerful.

Using Detect Balance, I came up with a score of 25, but once again I don't know how to properly balance Water Dependency and Seaweed Shifting.

So, to reiterate, Is this homebrew race balanced compared to official races?

Also my first homebrew review question, please let me know if I should format it differently. I thought adding notes about each section was the best, but it could be easier to have the whole statblock together instead.

I also just realized that I forgot to account for equipment and such when they shape... Whoops. If anybody has some tips for that, I'm all ears.

What's the source of the Grung race? I don't think it's official?

They're not official, however it's created by WotC for Extra Life in One Grung Above, so they're sorta kinda treated as such in some circles.

Google suggests kelpie is an Australian dog. What am I missing?

@SeriousBri Here's the forgotten realms wiki on it. The monster stat block is in Tales from the Yawning Portal

@SeriousBri Kelpies are Irish/Scottish shapeshifting water-spirits - and in Changeling the Dreaming they are rather disliked Thallain counterpart of Selkies.

Why is Seaweed Shifting rated so highly? It seems like a purely cosmetic disguise that automatically fails if the target gets even slightly close or if you're in bright light. The most reliable use-case I can see for it is transforming into a mount for a Small party member. Am I missing something?

@Elliot Like I said, I have zero idea how to properly account for it. If that's your take on it, and you can't think of any other uses, that would be useful as part of an answer, maybe with ways to improve it?

what's photosynthesis rated at?

@Trish I just put that as Doesn't Need to Eat

I'm not very familiar with Detect Balance, but I've seen other people's attempts to score every racial ability in some way, and every time I end up disagreeing with half of their reasoning. Which is probably a good thing; if we all agreed on which traits are better, then everybody would be playing the same character.
That said, one thing that helps with balance is to know what kind of game you're about to play, so you know the frequency at which different traits are likely to be used. Here's how I think the traits you've picked would fare at my table, but your mileage may vary.
Immunity to Aging
This is unlikely to come into play more than once, and the player might forget they even have it. As a DM, I would only rely on aging effects to give narrative weight to a threat, so this wouldn't affect balance.
Medium Size
Size interacts with many rules, so making playable Kelpies Medium is the safer choice. Even the Centaurs in Monsters of the Multiverse are Medium, despite the fact it means they can technically sit on the back of Large horses.
Creature type
Fey makes sense if Kelpies originate from the Feywild in your setting. Spells that specifically affect Fey are all flavored as attempts to ward off intruders (Forbiddance) or banish them to their plane of origin (Dispel Evil and Good). Not being a Humanoid grants immunity to some control spells (Hold Person) and necromancy spells (Create Undead), even the nice ones (Reincarnate).
Alternatively, Plant works best if you want to stick with the Tales of the Yawning Portal interpretation that describes them as animated seaweed. This would make the Kelpie sensitive to the Blight spell, detectable by Locate Animals or Plants, and a possible destination for Transport via Plants. I am particularly amused by the idea of a Fey popping out of a Kelpie player to mess with them.
Language
Aquan is the language of Water Elementals. If the Kelpie are Fey, they should probably understand Sylvan instead, otherwise I've yet to find a talkative Plant.
Speed 30 ft, Swim Speed 30 ft, Amphibious
For a playable race that's technically aquatic but is going to spend most of its time on land, this seems appropriate and aligns with the Sea Elf.
Water Dependency. Photosynthesis. 
Drinking water and food tend to be limiting only at low levels, unless you're venturing in an arid region and have to provide for others. This makes it difficult to comment on the balance of the Water Dependency and Photosynthesis features.
Seaweed Shifting
This feature is awkwardly phrased, especially the last sentence:

You cannot use your walking speed if you are in your true form, or the beast you are shifted into is unable to do so (such as a fish).

Speed is the distance a creature can walk; if something prevents a creature from walking, it does so by reducing its Speed to 0 ft. If the Kelpie cannot walk in its true form, then its Speed should have been written as 0 ft earlier, and the Seaweed Shifting feature should state that it raises the Kelpie's Speed.
But all this talk of Speed in a feature that's meant to be a form of disguise seems out of place. I would therefore keep the Kelpie's speed at 30 ft all the time, and rewrite the Seaweed Shifting feature like so:

As an action, you reshape your seaweed body to resemble a nondescript Humanoid or Beast that is Small or Medium. Your statistics are otherwise unchanged. The disguise is convincing, unless you are in bright light or the viewer is within 30 feet of you, in which case the seams between the seaweed strands are visible and your equipment is not concealed. You return to an amorphous mass of seaweed when you use a bonus action to do so, or when you die.

I clarified that the shape is nondescript and does not conceal the player's equipment; unlike Disguise Self, it won't let you pass as a specific individual, but it does let you take the shape of a horse lost in a marsh, or a wood elf bathing in a pond. If you want to make this ability more powerful, then you may want to look up the ability of the Changeling race, and more experienced DMs opinion of it.
Siren Song.
A level 1 spell which can be cast once a day isn't that powerful as a racial feature when you consider that some Elves gain a cantrip at level 1 a few spells at higher levels.


To summarize: the strongest features of your Kelpie are:

Immunity to some control spells thanks to not being a Humanoid
Swim speed and water breathing
Humanoid/Beast disguise which is noticeable in bright light or at 30 ft
Charm Person once a day

For comparison, the Sea Elf has the following:

Advantage on saving throws against being charmed and immunity to Sleep
Swim speed and water breathing
Proficiency in Perception
Darkvision (60 ft)
Long rest in 4h
Resistance to cold (added in MoM)
2 Weapon/Tool proficiencies swapped each long rest (added in MoM)

I used Sea Elf as a point of comparison since they have some features in common, and seeing those feature lists side by side makes me think your Kelpie could probably be stronger, or have a few features that will be useful often instead of mostly situational ones.

In your thinking, how where do Sea Elves figure in terms of balance/power compared to other races. You make that direct comparison, but it depends really on how over- or under-powered a Sea Elf is.

@Senmurv I think Elves are a good middle ground because they've been around since the beginning and have a lot of decent features for any build. Sea Elves just happen to also swim and breathe underwater, so they fill a similar niche. Your character being an Elf is likely to benefit them on every session, but being this Kelpie? Not so much.

It's on the weaker side and most of the abilities are situational
I really like the flavour of this race but I think mechanically it's somewhat lacking. How useful the abilities are is going to depend on the campaign you're playing and your DM's way of handling things but these are my observations based on my experiences:

Swimming speed + water breathing - it's the type of thing that feels nice to have on a character but in my experience it isn't really useful, if the DM wants the party to go underwater, they will make sure you have some way of doing it.
Siren Song - Charm Person is a string 1st level spell but only being able to cast it once per day is a big limitation. This feature will be most useful at the lower levels, later on its usefulness will taper off quickly.
Seaweed Shifting - a (much) weaker version of Changeling's Shapeshifter feature, very limited use. With a limit of 30 feet this is going to automatically fail before you even get close enough to someone to talk to them. It has use cases (e.g. leading someone into an ambush from a distance) but I don't think it will see a lot of use.
Photosynthesis - unless you're running a survival campaign where the food is scarce, it's unlikely to make a difference, and even then it won't be an issue past the first few levels.
Water dependency - how detrimental this is depends a lot on the campaign you're playing but usually would be a mild to moderate annoyance. Becomes largely irrelevant past tier 1.

Overall I think this race is quite weak. You could look at the Sea Elf race, it's a mostly aquatic official race like yours, and see how it compares to yours. At the very least consider giving it Darkvision too, the bottom of a lake is dark, it makes sense thematically. I would also change Seaweed Shifting to bring it to more in line with Disguise Person, give the observer a Perception check to spot the disguise instead of having it fail automatically.

+1 for the Darkvision suggestion. Also, the lake is even darker at night. :D

It's weak, very weak
The above statement is a sum up of my looking at it, below the use case for racial traits. I rate only the mechanics, I won't look at feel, idea or feature being "cool" or "good for roleplay", because it's not really quantifiable.
ASI, Age, Size
Nothing out of the ordinary, normal asi, medium size and the age being effectively immortal is of no consequence to gameplay. The "immunity to magical ageing effects" include (to my knowledge) an immunity to half of effect of one spell, which is probably no one ever going to cast on you, both because its optional content/settig specific, and because the spell sucks and enemies will have better alternatives. This won't even help you in case of ghosts, neither an immortal like you would care anyway, so this is nothing.
Creature Type
A fey is a bit better than being a human, especially in earlier levels, but it's basically a ribbon. Your "true" form I'll look at in shifting trait.
Speed
Usual speed so nothing fancy and swimming speed, which is occasionally useful, but its nothing to build around, just a circumstancial bonus.
Languages
Standard stuff.
Seaweed Shifting
This is, unfortunately, a dead feature. Or rather, the "true" form is, and the alternative is basically needed. Your "true" form cannot move, wield or carry anything, just float in water and exist. It has no concievable pros over the humanoid form, maybe save from attempting to hide butt-naked as a seaweed, which you almost certainly never will do in any campaign,  so you have no reason to ever turn into it. If that's the case, then from mechanical perspective why can you even transform? Why should you?
Okay, you can decrease your size to small, so maybe you can do that to squeeze somewhere, or fight in very small spaces without diadvantage, or pass through the space of Large creature undisturbed, as opposed to Huge. But all of that only if you are underwater, and not even, because you cannot really wield weapons as the seaweed. Maybe once or twice in entire campaign existence of this trait will come up, maybe not. Almost certainly no when it's not water-oriented campaign, so in my eyes this is next to no feature at all.
Amphibious
Good feature to go with your swimming speed.
Water Dependency
This is not as detrimental as this sounds, almost certainly not lethal, it's mostly annoying. But I can guarantee it will be more times annoying in an average campaign than Seaweed Shifting, Creature Type and Age, all together even appearing as relevant in the same campaign. So in my opinion it takes away all the benefits from the three, roughly equalizing them to zero, but it's my personal estimation only.
Photosynthesis
In some campaigns, this might come up from time to time and be useful, so as a ribbon it's not bad. There are campaigns where this will never come up, so a ribbon only.
Additionally, it's a bit unclear. It should be " As long as you spend had at least one hour of direct sunlight[...]", instead of " As long as you have had at least one hour of direct sunlight[...]". I do not know what it means to "have" a sunlight  for an hour. Yeah, I can guess what you had in mind/what it should do, but I should not be guessing how features work.
Siren Song
This is, as you saw in detect balance, a 1st level spell. Now, it is not of the new design (casting with your spellslots if you have any, choosing ability modifier etc.), neither this is a good spell, nor often cast - many long rests will pass when you won't even cast it once. So this feature is also weak.
TL.DR.
It's a really weak race. All features are circumstantial, some extremely so, there is nothing to build around or use to the fullest. And it has on top of that a flaw, not big, but it's there to ever remind you that there are close to 100 other races without any flaws, just different flavours of strengths. One feature that is unique here does not confer any real strengths to the race.
A triton, if you would take away its resistance, murder its spellcasting feature to be, I dunno, five times worse than originally, take away the darkvision and fish talk, and also strapped a flaw on them, then you would get this race. From the racial abilities alone, kelpie is not-a-human-all-the-time-but-they-should that can swim.
I suggest buffing, a lot. Right now there is no reason to play this race over other water-based races, like triton or genasi. Hell, any race will be better than kelpie with a ribbon a Fathemless Warlock get, at level one. Buff like crazy, then wander if it's too much. Now it's too little.
